# Flash movie transparent

Tags: html, css, flash

I've added a flash movie to my website, and set it's background to transparent, with wmode=transparent. This works flawlessly on Firefox, but on chrome, the background is just black. the website is http://galant-ks.com

Comment: Works on Chrome 15.0.874.121 Mac OS X. The background is transparent.

Comment: Well, I am using Chrome 15.0 on Windows XP, and it's not working.
Thanks Pierre.

Comment: Works on Chromium, Flash 11.1 and Win XP SP3

Answer (score 0):

it works on mine, Win 7 Chrome.If you did that, it's suppose to work. probably you can set the flash stage color to this Hex code '#EDEDED' and check if the wmode=transparent is set in both the `<object>` tag and `<embed>` tag.if you're using javascript to get the flash check that as well.it should resolve the issue.

Comment: It works fine on firefox, but on chrome it breaks down.
the stage color is already set to #EDEDED, and the wmode is set.
When I published from flash, it showed the HTML like this, with javascript.

Comment: check the version of flash you're using as well...are you using javascript to set the flash?

Comment: I just checked again to be sure: Installed Flash Player: 11.1.102
I didn't change anything, but the flash itself published the HTML like that, so I copy-pasted on my website

Comment: Check your publishing settings, see if it's set to default sometimes, the transparency layer might be messed up...

Comment: The problem is that I can't edit it in flash. I have the movie just as .swf so I can't edit it.

Comment: you can actually get a swf decompiler to get the exact source code of the file, if that would help.

Comment: I fixed it. It appears that using the rotate property on CSS, breaks the transparency on google. I used the decompiler you recommended, and rotated the image on flash.